# How to write a RegEx pattern to find the first word that is NOT one of the keywords?

Tags: regex

For example, my string may be `"private static final String myString;"` and I want to match the first word that is not in the following list `"private", "public", "protected", "static", "final"`, which in this case would be `"String"`. But this should give me the same result if my input was `"public String newString;"`

Answer (score 0):

Found it `"\b(?!public|protected|private|static|final\b)\w+"`